# Unable to click on filtered element using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, automation, webdriver-io

Unable to click on filtered element.

```
$$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel").filter(element => {
        return element.getText() === "face";
}).click();
```

I get the following error

```
$$(...).filter(...).click is not a function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) returns an array of elements, not an element.

You need to select an element from the list prior to calling `.click`:

```
.filter(...)[0].click();
```

Comment: ChanChow, you should mark this as the correct answer.

Comment: @Joundill I appreciate the gesture, but I think that will have only pinged me, not ChanChow (as the comment is on my answer, not on their question). It's also not really necessary, ChanChow isn't a new user and has accepted answers before. They may be busy or may be waiting to see if a more complete answer comes along, there's no reason to request it be accepted, OP can accept any answer they choose in their own time or none at all.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what @nick has explained, you can also use `find` which will be a more efficient method to achieve what you are looking for.

```
$$("app-filters-manager app-salesflow-panel mat-expansion-panel").find(element => {
        return element.getText() === "face";
}).click();
```

The `filter` method will iterate over all the elements even after finding one element which passes the condition, unlike find which will stop on the first occurrence.

Both of these will return undefined if none of the elements meet the condition and an error will be thrown when you try to execute click on undefined.

Comment: As you mentioned the iterator throws undefined error on second element. Why does that happen. The main goal of the filter or find is to find the element and perform some action

Comment: Do you have more than one element matching the selector  you have? Are these classes that you are using in your selector?